# EmberJS: Scroll to last item added in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have an ember app which consist of a div with fixed height and `overflow-y: scroll`.

Whenever I add an object a new div is added to the main div:

```
<div class="main-container">
<div class="added-item"></div>
<div class="added-item"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

As the list grows longer I would like to scroll to the last item after my Ember app has created a new record.

My template loop looks as follows:

```
<div class="task-comments">
  {{#each comment in comments}}
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="comment-content">
      <span class="author">
        <img {{bind-attr src=comment.userObject.userProfile.avatar}} alt="Avatar">
      </span>
      <p class="comment-user">
        <strong>{{comment.userObject.username}}</strong>
      </p>
      <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
    </div>
  </div> 
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

`.task-comments` is the main div in this case.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Can you post template code?  Is this each loop?

Comment: @Daniel added the template code.

Comment: Try smthing like `window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);` after pushing new comment. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key part is to execute the JS that scrolls to the desired position after the comment is added to the list and **rendered** on the screen.

In your view, schedule your scroll code to run using *Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {..})*. You can find a short working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vajuzovubo/3/edit).

If you're not familiar with the Ember run-loop, take a look [at the official docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/run-loop/#toc_what-happens-in-these-queues)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I read up on the Ember run-loop and got it working.